# Ах, сумасшедшая, право(,) сумасшедшая!

Tags: пунктуация

У Островского: Ах, сумасшедшая, право сумасшедшая! - после право нет запятой. По правилам она нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текстах встречаются оба варианта.

Классическим решением, как мне кажется, следует считать **обособление** вводного слова "право", но авторский вариант без обособления также возможен.

В этом случае "право" выступает в роли наречия, на которое падает **логическое ударение**: Ах, сумасшЕдшая, прАво сумасшедшая!

Сравнить: Ах, сумасшЕдшая, тОчно сумасшедшая!

Answer (score 2):

> *Ах, сумасшедшая, право сумасшедшая!* - после *право* нет запятой. По правилам она нужна?

По-моему, на усмотрение автора. (Кстати, во многих воспроизведениях этого предложения запятая после [***право***](https://www.google.ru/#q=%22%D0%90%D1%85,+%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F,+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F!%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&start=0) стоит.)

Наличие/отсутствие запятой после *право* несколько меняет интонацию прочтения. При отсутствии запятой ***право*** произносится (опять же, по-моему) с бОльшим логическим ударением.

А не ставить запятую можно по след. [**правилу**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127):

> **§ 94.** Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к
>   следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него
>   запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность
>   вводного слова к последующей части предложения)…

Comment: а есть еще правила на повторяющиеся слова. **Между одинаковыми словами, повторяющимися с интонацией перечисления для указания на длительность действия, для обозначения большого числа предметов или явлений, для подчеркивания степени качества и т.п., ставится запятая, например: Но он ехал, ехал, а Жадрина было не видать (Пушкин); Синий, синий, ходит он плавным разливом (Гоголь); И ближе, ближе все звучал грузинки голос молодой (Лермонтов); ...Все это ушло от меня навсегда, навсегда (Фадеев).**  ****

Comment: 2. **Если после повторяющегося слова или словосочетания с ним при чтении не делается пауза, то никакими знаками от последующих слов в предложении они не отделяются, например: Мне страстно, до боли страстно захотелось оскорбить или унизить их (Горький). Ср.: Все надрывались, буквально надрывались от хохота; Лес, сплошной лес окружал нас со всех сторон; Немногие, повторяю, только немногие по-настоящему понимали его.**

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужна. Во всяком случае не обязательна.
Здесь "право" находится в начале самостоятельного фрагмента, который можно трактовать как обособленный оборот. Поэтому по функции сближается с частицей и не обособляется.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2
(2. Вводное слово и обособленный оборот)

Answer (score 0):

"...Вводные слова и сочетания слов выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. Однако необходимо обратить внимание читателя на две трудности, связанные с пунктуацией при вводных словах.

Первая трудность заключается в том, что среди вводных слов и сочетаний очень мало таких, которые употребляются только как вводные и, следовательно, всегда обособляются (напр., *во-первых, по-моему, с позволения сказать*). В большинстве случаев **одни и те же слова могут употребляться как в роли вводных, так и в роли членов предложения** (как правило, сказуемых или обстоятельств) или служебных слов (союзов, частиц). Различия между ними проявляются в контексте. ..."  \ Словарь-справочник по пунктуации \ 
http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/605/↑Приложение_2

..здесь в словосочетании \возможно обособленный оборот|?|\ "право сумасшедшая" слово "право" -- член предложения. В контексте "действительно сумасшедшая". Потому запятая не обязательна или же вовсе не нужна.